# Get sum of repeating items as an array of IDS

Tags: mysql, sql

I have question regarding getting sum of the items by their IDS. Is there are any elegant way to do this with sql procedure? The IDS are coming from in array, for instance (10, 10, 11, 11, 12). So the sum should be 300. If I am right functions cannot take array as an parameter in mysql, so it can be procedure.

The closest what I could think of:

```
SELECT price FROM table WHERE FIND_IN_SET(ID, (10, 10, 11, 11, 12))
```

tho it doesn't work properly.
I know that SUM is almost does what I need, except it skips duplicate values, if there is a way to use it so it wouldn't skip, then it probably would be fastest. Table is below:

```
|---------------------|------------------|
|          ID         |       Price      |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          10         |         34       |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          11         |         99       |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          12         |         34       |
|---------------------|------------------|
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would create a derived table and `join`:

```
select sum(t.price)
from (select 10 as id union all
      select 10 as id union all
      select 11 as id union all
      select 11 as id union all
      select 12 as id 
     ) i join
     t
     on i.id = t.id;
```

Comment: Is it possible to loop through string array and input it for select union? 

for example:
`SET @testarr = '(1, 2, 3)';
select sum(products_storage.product_price)
from (select 1 as id union all
      select 2 as id union all
      select 3 as id 
     ) i join products_storage
     on i.id = products_storage.product_ID;`

Comment: @qwerty . . . MySQL doesn't have "arrays".  It is probably simplest to generate the code in the application.

Answer (score 0):

In MySQL 8.0, you can do this with running your input array thru [JSON_TABLE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-table-functions.html), which will interpret your array entries as rows.

This approach respects the array's order and doesn't skip duplicities, as it's not a filtering function like WHERE.

```sql
set @arr = '[10, 10, 11, 11, 12]';

select * 
from json_table(@arr, '$[*]' columns (id int path '$')) input
left join products using (id);

->  id  price
    10  34
    10  34
    11  99
    11  99
    12  34

select sum(price) 
from json_table(@arr, '$[*]' columns (id int path '$')) input
left join products using (id);

->  300
```